# How to expose Python callbacks to Fortran using modules

Tags: python, module, fortran, f2py

[This scipy documentation page](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/f2py/python-usage.html#call-back-arguments) about F2Py states:

> [Callback functions] may also be explicitly set in the module. Then
>   it is not necessary to pass the function in the argument list to the
>   Fortran function. This may be desired if the Fortran function calling
>   the python callback function is itself called by another Fortran
>   function.

However, I can't seem to find an example of how this would be done.

Consider the following Fortran / Python combination:

**test.f**:

```
subroutine test(py_func)

use iso_fortran_env, only stdout => output_unit

!f2py intent(callback) py_func
external py_func
integer py_func
!f2py integer y,x
!f2py y = py_func(x)

integer :: a
integer :: b

a = 12
write(stdout, *) a

end subroutine
```

**call_test.py**:

```
import test

def func(x):
    return x * 2

test.test(func)
```

Compiled with the following command (Intel compiler):

```
python f2py.py -c test.f --fcompiler=intelvem -m test
```

What changes would I have to take to expose `func` to the entire Fortran program in the form of a module, so that I could call the function from inside the subroutine `test`, or any other subroutine in any other fortran file in the project?

Comment: Does module code here help? https://code.google.com/p/f2py/wiki/FAQ2ed it looks as if new module is created, though I'm a bit confused whether it's a python module or fortran module.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the answer I found to this question.  Your comment reminded me.  See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me.  Note the absence of the parameters passed to test.  The python file is as stated in the question.

```
subroutine test()

use iso_fortran_env, only stdout => output_unit

!f2py intent(callback) py_func
external py_func
integer py_func
integer y,x
!f2py y = py_func(x)

integer :: a
integer :: b

a = 12
write(stdout, *) a

end subroutine
```

As an aside, I then wrapped `py_func` in a subroutine so that I could call it without having to declare the following in every file / function I use it:

```
integer y
y = py_func(x)
```